# Is it possible to keep 2 decimal numbers in a html email template

Tags: formula, email-template

Say that we have a Number field called Quote. In the email template, we want to force it to have two decimal numbers.

For example, if it is 4, we want to display 4.00. However, it is an html email template not a Visualforce one so I can't use controller.

And tried to use a formula field to convert it into text via:

```
text( floor( My_Number__c ) ) + "." + right( text( ( 1 + My_Number__c - floor( My_Number__c ) ) * 100 ), 2 )
```

However, since Quote__c itself is a formula field this new formula exceeds character limit by Salesforce.

Is there any way I can walk around this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me at my DE, not sure if this formula exceeds your limit or not.

```
LEFT(TEXT(My_Number__c * 1.001),LEN(TEXT(My_Number__c))+3)
```

Comment: I am still getting the same result. It shows something like 4 instead of 4.00

Comment: check my updated answer, it works for me

Comment: Thank you for this. It can work if the digits in the original number is less than 4. But I would argue that it won't work for scenarios which have more than 4 digits. Interesting solution though